# BitLocker add Numerical password

Tags: powershell, batch, bitlocker

I want have on PC add Numerical Password. What should I do. Because how much I searching for information can't find any specific. Any advice? Because in other device

Volume C: [Windows ] [OS Volume]

Size:                 475,85 GB
BitLocker Version:    2.0
Conversion Status:    Used Space Only Encrypted
Percentage Encrypted: 100,0%
Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
Protection Status:    Protection On
Lock Status:          Unlocked
Identification Field: Unknown
Key Protectors:
TPM
I see this: Volume C: [Windows ] [OS Volume]

Size:                 369,85 GB
BitLocker Version:    2.0
Conversion Status:    Used Space Only Encrypted
Percentage Encrypted: 100,0%
Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
Protection Status:    Protection On
Lock Status:          Unlocked
Identification Field: Unknown
Key Protectors:
TPM
**Numerical Password**
To got script or some advice how to achive my needed stuff.